# formatting a list into columns when there is nesting

Tags: jquery, list, nested

given an unordered list with arbitrary length but only ever 1 additional level of nesting:

```
<nav id="top_nav">
  <nav id="nav1">
    <ul>
      <li>saws</li>
      <li>drills
        <ul>
          <li>hammer-drills</li>
          <li>drill-drivers</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav id="nav2">...</nav>
  <nav id="nav3">...</nav>
</nav>
```

I want to format the list as columns by breaking up the original list into sibling lists (splitting every 14 li elements.)

After a search for plugins, I found nothing that columnizes nested lists based on the inner li.  I thought I would write my own script where I would split the list into additional 1st tier ul's and float them left (this is what i have so far):

For each nav block I get the size of the li elements and find the split points:

```
var max_height = 14;
$('#top_nav nav').each(function(){
    //step 1: mark 2nd tier li's with level2 class
  $(this).find('li ul li').addClass('level2');
  //step 2: mark 1st tier li's with level1 class
  $(this).find('li').not('.level2').addClass('level1');

  var li_list = $(this).find('li');
  var list_size = li_list.size();
  //find which elements to split on and number of times
  var split_points = (list_size / max_height) | 0; //bitwise OR is faster than Math.floor
  var split_point = max_height - 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < split_points; i++) {

    split_list(li_list.eq(split_point), li_list.eq(split_point + 1));
    split_point += max_height;

  }
});
```

the function "split_list takes" two consecutive li's (but not necessarily nested in the same ul) and splits them apart by injecting a pair of  and

  .

```
function split_list(li_obj, next_li_obj) {
  if (li_obj.length == 0 || next_li_obj.length == 0) {
  return false;
  }
  if (li_obj.attr('class') == 'level2' && next_li_obj.attr('class') == 'level2') {

    li_obj.append('</ul></ul>');
    next_li_obj.prepend('<ul><ul>');
  } else {
    li_obj.append('</ul>');
    next_li_obj.prepend('<ul>');
  }


}
```

I think this should work as it closes the list  then starts a new one  in the right places.  However it seems that jQuery "append" and "prepend" don't allow me to add unclosed tags.  It closes them for me.

Is there a way I can force jQuery to insert the exact string that I want?  Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just build an HTML string and then append/prepend it at the very end. Not only will this allow you to build it piece by piece with unclosed tags when necessary, it's also better performance (not that you'll notice!).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  aren't I appending/prepending html strings now?

Comment: Yes, but you wait until the very end, at which point the HTML string will be complete, meaning no unclosed tags.

Answer (score 0):

It pretty well explained here [Can I use Jquery to insert a closing </tr> tag and an opening <tr> tag inside a dynamic table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553383/can-i-use-jquery-to-insert-a-closing-tr-tag-and-an-opening-tr-tag-inside-a)
I think you should try rebuilding your structure, maybe using detach or creating new UL's and put there splitted LI's.